# On safari browser, paste content programmably will show system paste menu sometimes

Tags: javascript, safari, clipboard, paste, execcommand

When you want paste something in a contenteditable element by using javascript, there are two ways.

- Using the deprecated method `document.execCommand('paste')`
- Or using the new Clipboard API `navigator.clipboard.read()`

On safari browser, paste content programmably will show system paste menu sometimes, not always. The above two methods's behavior are same.

Is there anyway to disable this?

> My safari browser: v15.0.
>
> Test page ==> https://codepen.io/netsi1964/pen/QbLLGW?editors=0010

[image]

Comment: [execCommand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand)  takes three arguments.

Comment: The arguments doesn't help.